# Top self-intersection of the canonical divisor of a terminalization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, minimal-model-program

Let $(X,\Delta)$ be a $n$-dimensional log canonica model,
and let $Y\rightarrow (X,\Delta)$ be a log terminalization 
(meaning that $Y$ is the model obtained when we take a log resolution $\pi \colon  Y_0 \rightarrow (X,\Delta)$ and then
we run a MMP with respect to $\pi$).

Is it true that $K_Y^n \geq 0$? 
Or more general, which positivity conditions of $K_Y$ would we expect from the terminalization that other resolutions don't have?

Comment: Let $(X,\Delta)$ be $\mathbb P ^2$ and 4 general lines, then  $(X,\Delta)$ is a log canonical model and its terminalization is $\mathbb P ^2$ (unless I am confused by what you mean by terminalization). Therefore $K_{\mathbb P ^2}^2=-9<0$. Maybe you have something else in mind?

Comment: Or let $X=\mathbb P^2$, $\Delta=\emptyset$. :)

Comment: Joaquin: if you're running a relative mmp (i.e., with respect to $\pi$) then you cannot expect global positivity properties.